# Saving all of User Tweets into a DataFrame Tweepy Python

Tags: python, tweepy

Using Tweepy, the following link is a script to scrape all tweets and save them as CSV:

https://gist.github.com/yanofsky/5436496

I am trying to save all the extracted tweets into a Pandas DataFrame instead of using CSV. I am using the following code:

```
data = pd.DataFrame(data=[tweet.text for tweet in tweets],columns=['Tweets'])
display(data.head(10))
```

However, I am unable to do so.

Code2:

```
extractor = twitter_setup() # We create an extractor object:

tweets = extractor.user_timeline(screen_name="@thedubaimall", count=300) # We create a tweet list as follows:
print("Number of tweets extracted: {}.\n".format(len(tweets)))
```

Comment: What's the error? Please include the full traceback.

Comment: Using the code I am unable to return tweepy.models.ResultSet, which can then be converted to DataFrame